# Coordinate Concourse CI Same-Repo Checks?

Tags: concourse, concourse-pipeline, concourse-git-resource, concourse-task

I have a Concourse CI pattern where multiple pipelines are defined in one repo. I want to test the **entire** repository, and then only when certain files have changed (i.e. the pipeline-specific YAML) apply those pipelines which have changed. It *mostly* works - except that it will instantly apply the pipeline when those files have changed without waiting for the whole repo to get tested.

Here's the pertinent parts of my config:

```yaml
resources:
  - name: "repo-self"
    type: git
    source:
      uri: "git@github.com:some-repo.git"
      branch: main
  - name: "repo-self-pipeline-1" # for triggering setting that pipeline
    type: git
    source:
      uri: "git@github.com:some-repo.git"
      branch: main
      paths:
        - "concourse/pipeline-1/*"
jobs:
  - name: testing
    plan:
      - get: "repo-self"
        trigger: true
      - in_parallel:
          - task: "test-1"
          - task: "test-2"
          - task: "test-3"
  - name: "set-pipeline-1"
    plan:
      - in_parallel:
          - get: "repo-self"
            passed:
              - testing
          - get: "repo-self-pipeline-1"
            trigger: true
      - set_pipeline: "pipeline-1"
        file: "repo-self-pipeline-1/concourse/pipeline-1/main.yaml"
```

I cannot simply add the same `passed` directive to set the pipeline as that git repo resource isn't directly tested. And I don't want to **also** run it through testing as ideally it's the same git sha - it just happens to have the files changed that I care about.

Is there some way to gate or otherwise lock "repo-self-pipeline-1" to the same sha as "repo-self"?

Comment: Before I try to make sense out of that question, was `passed: [linting]` intentional or was it supposed to point at `testing`?

Comment: Ugh, unintentional. Edited my post and fixed. In my attempts to not include extraneous info in that config, I missed a couple things. Thanks for asking for clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Add `- get: "repo-self-pipeline-1"` without a trigger to the `testing` job. No need to run tests on that repo. Then add `passed: testing` to the second repo in the second job. That should do the trick.

Comment: Aha! I don't know why I didn't think of that. Fantastic.

Comment: Turns out this isn't quite matching my needs. This approach is gating the second repo to go with the first, but it isn't necessarily the same git sha.